# Powering 1920 leds with 32 strips of 60 ws2812b led strips each (32 meters)

Tags: power-supply, power, raspberry-pi, led-strip, ws2812b

I'm tring to build a led display with 32 strips of ws2812b led strips with 60 leds each. That's a total amount of 1920 leds. 
How many power supplies should I buy? Given the max current of 50mA per leds, that's a 50mA x 60 x 32 = 96A. I'm going to buy to power supplies of 5V 60A (https://www.amazon.it/HAILI-Trasformatore-Adattatore-Alimentazione-Telecamere/dp/B07Y38SMQ3/). What should be the connection of the strips? Should I power every side of each strip? I made a schema:

[image]

Do you have any suggestions to connect all these cables with each other? (32 + 32 each side).

The Led strip I'm using is the 1m 60 IP30 + WS2812BECO Black PCB as pictured here: [image]

Comment: The ws2812b is not a strip it's an individual RGB LED as far as I remember. You are asking someone to confirm that the cabling arrangement for a power supply with no data sheet connected to some unspecified strips of LEDs is OK. Your expectations may be too high.

Comment: Do not draw a schematic in this case.  Rather draw the actual wiring diagram showing how you plan to connect the LEDs.  You will need two 60 A supplies.

Comment: Your are right, the LEDs are connected as pictured in the red box. There are 60 leds on each strip.

Comment: How far apart will the strips be placed? [`60 leds/m = 18 watt/meter`](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/489770/powering-1920-leds-with-32-strips-of-60-ws2812b-led-strips-each-32-meters#comment1244918_489773) that's 300 mW per LED+driver - 10 mA for each driver? Anyway: 18 W * 32 = 576 W (cooling?) - 115.2 A.

Answer (score 0):

The wiring of the power depends on the layout of the strips, if they are connected exactly like in the image, i would switch build a ring supply (powering both sides of the strips.

Please be aware of the following:

- 5V, 96A is no joke in terms of security. If the wires touch, there will be a huge arc.
- 5V 96A requires large wire (like 25mm2)
- Each strip of 60 LED's requires 3.6A, check if the strips are made for this current
- Check if its possible to drive 1920 led from one data pin. Shifting out data for 1920 led is around 76.8k bits of data

Comment: 5V, 96A is no joke in terms of security. If the wires touch, there will be a huge arc.
--> **Another solution would be buy 10 power supply that provide 5V 10A if it's more safe**;
Each strip of 60 LED's requires 3.6A, check if the strips are made for this current --> **from the vendor, I can see that 60 leds/m = 18 watt/meter**;

Check if its possible to drive 1920 led from one data pin. Shifting out data for 1920 led is around 76.8k bits of data --> **Raspberry Pi Zero W has 512MB of RAM, I'll check how much memory is available**

Comment: @DiegoBraga how fast do you want/need to update the LEDs? It’s not a matter of memory (this is insignificant) but speed of the data link to the LEDs.

Comment: @jcaron I want it to be really fast. I checked yesterday and the free memory on the Raspberry Pi Zero was 44MB, so pretty much space for the shifting data. What I'm concern is the connection of the 2 power units in the diagram I've attached: should I connected each side of the strip for both positive and negative lines? or should I attach just the input side for the positive line?

Comment: @DiegoBraga the WS2812 take minimum 19.2us per LED per frame + 280us reset. For 1920 LEDs thats minimum 37144us per frame, leading to an absolute max frame rate of 26.9fps. _if you can get the timing exactly right_. Realistically, if your bit-banging on a pi, theres a good chance you want more marging on that, and I wouldn't want to rely on anything more than 20fps.

Comment: That also means you'll have a close to 40ms phase difference in update point from the top left to bottom right. This probably won't be a problem, but might cause interesting shutter effects if it it interacts with anything else. It might be worth considering a horizontal interleaved pattern as used by early CRTs.